# Difference between CREATE CAST and CREATE CONVERSION

Tags: sql, postgresql

In postgres, it seems there are two customizable ways to convert one value type into another via SQL, [`CREATE CONVERSION`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createconversion.html) and [`CREATE CAST`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createcast.html). What is the difference between these two items, for example what might be an example of where one might be used over another?

Comment: No there isn't, read the links again.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver sure, which part though? "No" meaning there is no difference?

Comment: No as they are not the same thing. Read the links in particular the first line under **Description**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cast has nothing to do with a conversion.

A cast converts data from one data type to another, while a conversion converts a string from one encoding to another (and does not change the data type at all).

What you are looking for is a cast. Forget about the conversion.

Comment: thanks for clarifying. What would be an example when someone would ever want to use an encoding conversion on stored data?

Comment: When calling `convert_to` or `convert_from` to convert between these encodings.